# Como transformar os valores da variável do meu data.frame em colunas no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponhamos que tenho o seguinte data.frame:

```
print(DADOS)

CODIGO  QTDE  MÊS
001     4     1
001     1     1
001     3     2  
001     2     3
001     3     3
001     4     3
001     2     4
001     2     4
001     1     5
001     5     6
001     2     6
```

Mas preciso transformar os valores da variável MÊS em colunar. Que seria o data.frame deste jeito:

```
print(DADOS_TRANSFORMADOS)

CODIGO  QTDE  MÊS  QTDE  MÊS  QTDE  MÊS  QTDE  MÊS  QTDE  MÊS  QTDE  MÊS
001     4     1    3     2    2      3   2     4    1     5    5     6
001     1     1    NA    2    3      3   2     4    NA    5    2     6
001     NA    1    NA    2    4      3   NA    4    NA    5    NA    6
```

Eu tentei dividir meu data.frame em 6 partes filtrando por cada mês e depois usar a função `join` para unir mês a mês, mas não deu certo.

Como posso transformar os valores da variável do meu data.frame em colunas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `tidyverse` para fazer o que deseja. Primeiro, crio um exemplo reprodutível:

```
set.seed(123)

df_1 <- data.frame(
 cod = 1, 
 qtde = sample(x = 1:4, size = 11, replace = TRUE), 
 mes = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6)
)
```

Agora, a análise:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key = mes, value = qtde)


# A tibble: 3 x 8
#    cod     n   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     3     3     3     2     4     4
#2     1     2     4    NA     3     1    NA     3
#3     1     3    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA
```

Você pode usar o argumento `fill` para preencher os `NA`s com o algarismo que deseja. Por exemplo, substituir `NA`s por `0`:

```
df_1 %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key = mes, value = qtde, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 8
#    cod     n   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`
#  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     3     3     3     2     4     4
#2     1     2     4     0     3     1     0     3
#3     1     3     0     0     3     0     0     0
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Comment: Neves, se no meu caso a base dados for muito maior, por exemplo se no meu campo 'size' fosse maior que 100 mil linhas, como poderia, montar o vetor 'mes' sem precisar escrever cada linha?

Comment: Como assim "sem presisar escrever cada linha"?

Comment: É que no exemplo  você escreveu as variáveis no vetor, `mes = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6)`, mas depois de alguns teste eu entendi que realmente não necessitava e selecionei com a função group_by a coluna MÊS diretamente.